# Require or Include PHP class : can't access functions

Tags: php, wordpress, class, include, require

I am working on a Wordpress-based site.
I'm trying to include a PHP class, and seem to have success, though I can't use the functions within the class (functions are not recognized).

Note:
I'm including the class inline via a custom template page within my WP theme.

Comment: How are you trying to access the functions?

Answer (score 3):

Try to instantiate the class first, then access the function through your variable

```
$a = new Class();
$a->function();
```

But some functions are private, read the documentation of the class first..

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.
Instantiated the class; ran the function through the instance; and it worked.  Thanks for your help.